# I am trying to list out coursework materials using Google Appscript Google Classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-classroom

I'm trying to get the data out of my google classroom course I'm using google app script. I want to get the title and the id to appear in a google sheet. my reference for understanding is https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-classwork#retrieve_student_responses I want to retrieve student responses from the assignments in google classroom.

But I first need access to the courseId. which can be found here https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list

this is the code i am using to get the course work from the google app script API

```
function getCourseWork(courseId) {
  var id = [];
  var title = [];
  var optionalArgs = {
      pageSize: 100
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.list(courseId, optionalArgs)
  var courseWork = response.courseWork

  for (var i = 0; i <= courseWork.length; i++) {
    try {
      var courseWorkId=id.push(courseWork[i].id);
      var courseWorkTitle=title.push(courseWork[i].id);
    } catch (err) {
       return { "id":courseWorkId, "title":courseWorkTitle}
   }
 }
}
```

I'm. not sure why the code is not working.

Comment: Does it do anything?  If you expect a large return you'll probably need to use the paged version which utilized the `pageToken optional argument`

Comment: can you provide a link to what you are referring to? @MetaMan

Comment: I have a `pagesize`

Comment: Does it do anything?

Comment: no it says I can't get the courseid

Comment: What is the exact error and please indicate which line it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232616/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-metaman).

Comment: on the 7th line there is an issue
I then added var courseId = importCourses(courseId[0]); to see if I could pull the courseid from the import course function which is pulling the course ids from my courses in google classroom. @MetaMan

Comment: Where are you getting courseId from?

Comment: Google Classroom